# Section in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have been trying to work out how to add section headers to my UITableView, for days and days, researching as best I can, reading it seams hundreds of pages, can someone at least point me in the right direction, please?

I have an array:

```
  recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipe1, recipe2, recipe3, recipe4, nil];
```

That is feed from 132 of the below:

```
Recipe *recipe1 = [Recipe new];
recipe1.name = @"Almonds";
recipe1.image = @"almonds.jpg";

Recipe *recipe2 = [Recipe new];
recipe2.name = @"Apples";
recipe2.image = @"apples.jpg";
```

And so on...

And am looking for:

```
A
Almonds
Apples
B
Bananas
Blackcurrants...
```

There are 27 sections.

Comment: What code have you tried to reorganise your `recipes` array into an dictionary and array of sections (which are the keys to the dictionary, sorted)?

Comment: The first thing you need to do, as Wain suggests in his comment, is to organize your data in a way that's appropriate for a sectioned table view. A simple single array is not a good data structure. For a sectioned table, it's common to use an array of arrays, or a dictionary. In your case, I think a dictionary would be best -- the keys would be the letters of the alphabet, and the values would be an array of recipe objects whose name starts with the same letter as the key. Think about, and try, code to accomplish this, and then edit your question to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want section header title, you can use UITableViewDataSource method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Or you can set your custom view as header using UITableViewDelegate method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

The controller implementing these, needs to be the delegate/datasource of your table view.

Answer (score 0):

For alphabets exclusively, Try something like:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if ([aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0) return nil;

  return [alphabet objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

Here alphabet is NSArray declared in ViewDidLoad. Reference([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286744/uitableview-alphabet))

```
alphabet = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",...,@"Z",nil];
```

For custom:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 if (section==0) {
    return @"";
} else if (section==1) {
    return @"Actions";
} else if (section==2) {
    return @"Attached To";
}

return @"";
}
```

And for alignment of text try method below.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 UILabel * sectionHeader = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
 sectionHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 sectionHeader.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
 sectionHeader.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
 sectionHeader.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

 switch(section) {
    case 0:sectionHeader.text = @"TITLE ONE"; break;
    case 1:sectionHeader.text = @"TITLE TWO"; break;
    default:sectionHeader.text = @"TITLE OTHER"; break;
 }  
   return sectionHeader;
  }
```

Comment: so you would have 27 cases

Comment: I am close to getting it working I think, at the moment, I only have one section header, for all the array, so am trying to workout how to split the array in the sections, to show the headers. I am so new to this, I could be running before I walk, but am enjoying the challenge! Thank you all for all you help!!! akash, thanks for the example! that really helps me!!

Comment: If you want to be in the right direction , I suggest you to follow the guys suggestions in the [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915864/section-in-a-uitableview/22915935?noredirect=1#comment34978321_22915864). Your need to put the data together, don't separate them